# Bodyparser for multipart Nodejs

Tags: node.js, middleware, body-parser

[image]
[image]So I want to begin with my body-parsers and also I'm using the 'multer'

My multer options :

```
var multer = require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, '/root/Unicon-Oauth/Resources/profile_images/')
},
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
}
});

var pfImage = multer({storage:storage});
```

Body Parsers at server.js

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true,limit: '20MB',parameterLimit:10000}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

I have a route like that

```
router.post('/edit',[auth.isAuthenticated,pfImage.single('pImage')],actions.edit);
```

function is like that

```
function edit(req,res)
{
  console.log(req.body);
}
```

console log output :

> Blockquote
>
> {"------WebKitFormBoundaryGS8GEzQls8xRP6nt\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name":"\"_id\"\r\n\r\n58a4735cfa328b7e9eaf6a3a\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryGS8GEzQls8xRP6nt\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"city\"\r\n\r\nKayseri\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryGS8GEzQls8xRP6nt\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name\"\r\n\r\nali\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryGS8GEzQls8xRP6nt\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryGS8GEzQls8xRP6nt--\r\n"}

How can I parse this as req.body ?

Comment: Are you trying to pass the image data through the url?

Comment: nope going through postman I added the screenshots

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're sending a multipart/form-data request *but* you're overriding the Content-Type and setting it to a *different* type (application/x-www-form-urlencoded), which is a totally different format. If you remove this override, it should be fine.